# WordPress foreach loop pulling 3 videos by tag

Tags: wordpress, foreach

I am trying to get 3 of my videos I tagged in WordPress with the tag "video."

The code in the theme I got doesn't work, I tried to edit it and all but I can't get any further.

```
global $post;

$tag = get_term_by( 'name', 'video', 'post_tag', 'ARRAY_A' );
$videos = get_posts(array('tag__in' => $tag, 'showposts' => '3'));

foreach($videos as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
    echo "<div class=\"videoframe\" id=\"videoframe\">".woo_get_embed('embed', '520', '293')."</div>";
endforeach;
```

So, I'm filling up `$tag` with the "video" tag (`post_tag`) and make it an `array_a`. Then, I'm filling up `$videos` with the posts that have the tag I've put in `$tag` and I would like the 3 latest.

Then, I `foreach` the post I got out of `$videos` I want to embed by using the `woo_get_embed` function.

Unfortunately, somehow the tag comparison doesn't go well, because it echoes posts without the video tag and because of that it doesn't echo anything at all.

Comment: `showposts` is deprecated use `posts_per_page` but that's not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tag__in` expects an array with ID's
You are giving it an array with all info about the video.

You want `'tag_id' => $tag['term_id']`

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed the problem! I'll also replace showposts with posts_per_page later!